# How to run aloe tests in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, bdd

I have a set of files `.feature` and i'd like to run/debug it from PyCharm. 
in PyCharm professional only lettuce and behave are available.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late, but an install of the Python library [Aloe](https://aloe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) may be what you need. This is usable for Python 3+ and takes .feature files for input.